# Where does a user share in Laravel Jetstream Inertia?

Tags: laravel-9, inertiajs, laravel-jetstream

Laravel 9, Inertia, VUE 3, Jetstream.
The user is called in the AppLayout component.

```
$page.props.user
```

Where in Laravel is this user being passed? I looked at HandleInertiaRequests but it's not there.

Comment: are you sure it's not in `HandleInertiaRequests.php`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

look at vendor/laravel/jetstream/src/Http/Middleware/ShareInertiaData.php